# Hash element is nil when pass to method through Sidekiq worker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

When I call method directly everything works:

```
Photo.new.init_albums_comments(group_id: @group.id, owner_id: @group.owner_id, user_id: current_user.id)
```

But when I call this method through Sidekiq worker something strange happens:

```
InitPhotoWorker.perform_async(group_id: @group.id, owner_id: @group.owner_id, user: current_user.id)
```

**worker**

```
class InitPhotoWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  sidekiq_options retry: 3, :queue => :critical
  Sidekiq::Logging.logger.level = Logger::DEBUG

  def perform(photo_params)
    Photo.new.init_albums_comments(photo_params)
  end
end
```

**method:**

```
def init_albums_comments(photo_params)
    Rails.logger.debug "#{photo_params}"
    Rails.logger.debug "#{photo_params[:owner_id]}"
...
end
```

In my log I see that hash photo_params is ok: `{"group_id" => "1", "owner_id" => "54454545", "user_id" => "1"}`
but log for hash key `:owner_id` shows that has no value. What's wrong with it or with me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Hash seem to have string keys:

```
Rails.logger.debug "#{photo_params['owner_id']}"
```

From the Sidekiq documentation:

The arguments you pass to perform_async must be composed of simple JSON datatypes: string, integer, float, boolean, null, array and hash. The Sidekiq client API uses JSON.dump to send the data to Redis. The Sidekiq server pulls that JSON data from Redis and uses JSON.load to convert the data back into Ruby types to pass to your perform method. Don't pass symbols or complex Ruby objects (like Date or Time!) as those will not survive the dump/load round trip correctly.

Comment: hm.. sure you're right. but it was symbol at start, why it becomes string? and I have 3 more workers for other methods that look absolutely same and work fine...

Comment: It becomes a string, because JSON.load can't know if your keys were symbols or strings before: `JSON.load "{\"one\": 1}" # => {"one"=>1}`

Comment: yes... you are right. other of my workers also have this problem. thanks man)